# how to save data from differnt layouts in android studio with a single button

Tags: android

I have been scratching my head about how to save user data from different layouts. My application is setup to collect user data from 5 different pages then on the last page has a button to save that data from all the 5 pages.

I have created all the 5 layouts as well as classes and set the content view by id to reference the XML layouts but i cant seem to figure out how i can make the save button on the last page save all that data. Saving data from one layout i can but not from different layouts.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to do that depends on your requirement.

1. You can use shared preference to save data and when you save it clear that data. In can user closes the app or app gets removed from memory in any case user's data will loose.
2. If there is no need to persist data on app close you can use a static class to store those values.
3. This way is not a efficient one but can be used. Pass data one intent to another till save button activity, if you are using activity as pages.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is send data from fist page to the second and so on till you reach the last page with the button and then save all the data which you have collected through intents

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);   
String strName = null;
i.putExtra("STR", strName);
```

You can send data using the above code and use below code to recieve data and store in a variable and send to the next activity till you reach the last activity then save all data

```
String newString;
Intent in= getIntent();
newString = in.getStringExtra("STR");
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to create a custom Application class that extends Application and add it to your AndroidManifest.xml.

Inside the class you can code the proper getters and setters.

Basic example:

```
public class DataApplication extends Application{

    private String a;

    public String getData(){
        return a;
    }

    public void setData(String data){
        a=data;
    }
}
```

To access the data from your activities, do something like this:

```
DataApplication d;
d = (DataApplication) getApplicationContext();
```

Edit: once your application is terminated, all data is gone.